# How to create a list of actions<T>

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, delegates

I want to create a event hub of sorts with a dictionary (Type, Action(T)). This would allow me to lookup an action based on the type of the object I was given and run the correct action. However the compiler does not like me having different types of actions in the same dictionary. So I tried using a dynamic typed action but that still gave me an error when trying to convert T to dynamic. I then tried adding a constraint on the generic so that everything was derived from the same abstract base class but that also did not solve the problem.

Is there any way to make this work? I am fine with using something like reflection as long as your big performance hit is only when you register the method and not on every call.

```
var functions = Dictionary<Type, Action<dynamic>>();

void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler)
    where T : BaseClass
{
    functions.Add(typeof(T), handler);
}

void CallMethod<T>(T data)
{
    functions[data.GetType()].Invoke(data);
}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please tag accordingly

Answer (score 0):

After some more playing around I found a solution that compiles. I have not yet tested this to see if it has a large performance impact. If you can improve on this please let me know.

```
    var functions = Dictionary<Type, Action<dynamic>>();

    void RegisterDynamicHandler<T>(Action<dynamic> handler)
    {
        Functions.Add(typeof(T), handler);
    }

    public void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler)
        where T : BaseClass
    {
        if (functions.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            throw new RegisterHandlerException();

        Action<dynamic> dynamicAction = (Action<dynamic>)handler;
        RegisterDynamicHandler<T>(dynamicAction);
    }
```